# Parsing stdclass object broken XML

Tags: php, stdclass

Using a third party API, I am attempting to parse the output that I get. I'm being returned a StdClass object that contains some XML but not properly formatted XML as follows:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [any] => <data xmlns="" count="2" count_available="3366"><row id="1"><description1>testing 1</description1></row><row id="2"><description1>testing 2</description1></row></data>
)
```

What is the best and easiest way to parse this so i can retrieve fields such as 'description1' ?

Comment: Have you tried loading it from this object with something like `$xml = simplexml_load_string($object->any); echo $xml->asXML();` to check it?

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, that does indeed return the two descriptions in the XML, but with no seperation between them, what is the best way to return these as inidividual items?

Comment: You may just have to do the old fashioned way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the content from the object and then you can use SimpleXML to access the values.  SimpleXML uses object notation to access the XML elements, so this loops over the `<row>` elements in the document and for each one outputs the `<description1>` element (casting to a string otherwise you end up with a SimpleXMLElement object)...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($object->any);
foreach ($xml->row as $row){
    echo (string)$row->description1.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew the solution would be simple but I was getting very confused when trying to use simple_xml_load_string and pulling attributes from it. This works great :)